# How can you change the default width of semantic-ui sidebars?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Semantic-ui sidebars are 275px wide. Where should I add the css/js which makes them wider or narrower?

Their code is

```
.ui.sidebar {
   width: 275px!important;
   margin-left: -275px!important;
}
```

If I modify this, then the change is global for all the sidebars.
If I change their content's width, semantic-ui ignores my change and overrides it with the default 275px.

You can find the sidebar example here:
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples

Comment: Maybe use its size variations?

Comment: Yeah, that's one way, except that I needed something more custom. I ended up creating a new size variation. This seems to be the accepted way to do it for now. The semantic-ui folks plan on adding css variables: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/216 ; they will make this task even easier.

Comment: Yeah, the 'wide' and 'very wide' variations have a huge difference, which is probably not what you're looking for, so your solution is probably the best :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is to just add a new class:

```
.ui.custom.sidebar {
  width: 315px !important;
  margin-left: -315px !important;
}

.ui.active.custom.sidebar {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}

.ui.active.right.custom.sidebar {
  margin-left: -315px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception): "Using !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets."

"Always look for a way to use specificity before even considering !important"

I would recommend using specificity to solve this problem, not `!important` as it is considered a bad practice. Assuming these styles are being applied to a `div` you can be more specific like this:

```
div.ui.sidebar {
   width: 275px
   margin-left: -275px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `max-width` to a bigger value instead of the default one in your css.

```
max-width: 1000px !important;
```